# Does wearing full armor set grant bonus?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In example, if I make my companion wear full set of Dwarven armor, will she get some kind of reward bonus (like in Diablo) for wearing full set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only armors that have a sort of "set bonus" are in the DLCs. All other armors only have the perk bonuses (+25%) for a matching set.

From Dawnguard:

- Dawnguard Light - 25% less damage from Vampires and Drain Life spells
- Dawnguard Heavy - same bonus

From Dragonborn:

- Ahzidal's Armor - 10% Enchanting with the boots + *exactly* 3 other items from the set of 7. More or less than 3 other items will not activate the bonus.
- Deathbrand Armor - each piece's enchantment gets stronger when wearing more pieces of the set

Also from Dragonborn, but weapons:

- Soulrender and Bloodscythe - absorb health and magicka, chance to reduce armor and dispel magic when used together

Comment: Do you know if these set bonuses work for a follower as well?

Comment: I don't believe so

Answer (score 5):

No, there are not armor set bonuses in Skyrim.

The closest thing is a range of perks that will improve various attributes when wearing a full set from a particular category. [This wiki page details this](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_Sets_(Skyrim)) towards the bottom of the page.

However, perks obviously don't affect your companion.

Comment: Some followers have perks, including ones that give full set bonuses.

Comment: @DCShannon you seem to have a different interpretation of set bonus to what I had, but useful information indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Some [followers](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Follower_(Skyrim)) have perks. These are not listed on the Elder Scrolls Pages, generally, but a GameFAQs forum user was kind enough to use the Creation Kit to identify and list them. [This list](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/65578014) is four years old, so it could be out of date if patches have changed things.

Based on that list, there are eight followers that have perks that give them bonuses for full sets of armor:

**Well Fitted**

> 25% armor bonus if wearing all Heavy Armor: head, chest, hands, feet

Golldir

**Tower of Strength**

> 50% less stagger when wearing only Heavy Armor

Golldir, Mjoll

**Custom Fit**

> 25% armor bonus if wearing all Light Armor: head, chest, hands, feet

Belrand, Karliah, Mercer Frey, Celann, Durak, Serana

Answer (score 1):

There are set bonuses in skyrim, with or without the DLC, for instance, wearing a full set of Daedric Armor increases your intimidation stat checks by 10%, which means you only need to meet 90% of their required points, to be able to intimidate.
You can see this on the wiki's and test them in game, as I have.

Comment: Can you link to the information on said wiki?

Answer (score 0):

The Ahzidal set works with the boots and any other 3 relics(dragon priest mask, helmet, armor, gauntlets and rings). Only a total of 4 items equipped, though. Equip 5 items and it cancels the effect. Deathbrand armor requires dual wielding for the one handed bonus to work.

There is a hidden bonus to both the nightingale armor set and the shrouded armor set. When you wear all 4 pieces of either set you get an extra 25 points of armor. Not that great since there is no perk that lets you improve them twice as much, but with smithing skill, gear and  a potion should make it easier to hit the armor cap(just need more light armor perks).